# 0x800a139e -JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013

I have getting following exception when i run the application in IE in output window of VisualStudio 2013

Exception was thrown at line 5288, column 6 in http://localhost:49624/Static/scripts/apps/dx/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 6 in http://localhost:49624/Static/scripts/apps/dx/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

But when i run the application in Firefox it will not throw the exception.So please let me how can handle the exception

Comment: have you included both 1.8.2 and 1.9.1 Jquery libs ? if yes please use only 1. If you are targeting IE8 using 1.9.X makes sense, otherwise please move to Jquery 2.X.X if you intend working on IE9+

Comment: With your links pointing to localhost, we will never be able to see it. You are using an older version of jQuery. Why not go download the current version 1.11.2 or 2.1.3 and see if the problem goes away.